# Where does samba_share_t come from

Tags: selinux

I have samba installed, selinux in enforcing mode, samba shares works fine.

But I am not sure where samba_share_t is defined?

`semanage fcontext -l | grep samba_share_t` does not return anything.

Another questions is how do I know if there are other selinux security context not listed by semanage.

I found this link http://danwalsh.livejournal.com/14195.html
but `man samba_selinux` says `No manual entry for samba_selinux`

`man samba_selinux` worked after installed `selinux-policy-doc`

I assumed that `semanage fcontext -l` will give me a complete list of all selinux security file context but it is not that case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`semanage fcontext -l` will only return the list of file contexts that are in use.

You can find the man page `samba_selinux` and `*_selinux` in the `selinux-policy-devel` package.

Fedora 24:

```
sudo dnf install selinux-policy-devel
```

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7:

```
sudo yum install selinux-policy-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the `seinfo` tool to look at file and other contexts that may not be used elsewhere.  It will show all defined contexts.

To answer your question

```
seinfo -t
```

`seinfo` is in the `setools-console` package in RHEL7.